# Use MapBox GL JS with React - Error: Invalid type: ‘container’ must be a String or HTMLElement

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am currently adding MapBox to a React project, and was using [this tutorial](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/use-mapbox-gl-js-with-react/) as a guide.

When I add the ref attribute to the map div, I'm get the following error (as have [others](https://medium.com/@kohenchia/examples-dont-work-anymore-and-it-s-not-clear-how-to-use-the-same-technique-in-2019-b4325cf3c5ad))

`“Error: Invalid type: ‘container’ must be a String or HTMLElement.”`

I reached out to MapBox support last week but haven't heard back from them, so any helpful insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the linked docs to React itself? You might need to call `React.createRef()` before being able to use the ref.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem while following the tutorial. I think it has to do with the updated way React deals with Refs (https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

Create the ref within the constructor using :

```
this.mapContainer = React.createRef();
```

And then access the ref when defining the map using:

```
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: this.mapContainer.current,
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
    center: [this.state.lng, this.state.lat],
    zoom: this.state.zoom
```

Finally,

```
<div ref = {this.mapContainer} className = "mapContainer"/>
```

Comment: I had to convert my functional React component into a Class to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

In your useEffect, make sure that your mapContainer.current is not null with this :
if (!mapContainer.current) return;

Answer (score 0):

For me solutions was to set class of div which I want to contain map and then in `componentDidMount()` referenced through `querySelecter` instead of `createRef`. And it works in Gatsby so far.